# Runtime error - skipping a line of user input (Scanner)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In my tester file, I am trying to receive 3 inputs from the user however only 2 of the inputs are received and it seems that the program is skipping over the in.nextLine() line of code. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IngredientTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        /*These 3 inputs work */
        System.out.println("Please enter Ingredient name.");
        String inputName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Ingredient measurement type.");
        String inputType = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Ingredient amount");
        double inputAmount = in.nextDouble();

        Ingredient inputIngredient = new Ingredient(inputName,inputType,inputAmount);
        System.out.println(inputIngredient.getName() + "- " + inputIngredient.getAmount() + " " + inputIngredient.getMeasurement());

        System.out.println("Please enter Ingredient name.");
        inputName = in.nextLine();
                /* ^ the input above does not work, but the ones below do work */
        System.out.println("Please enter Ingredient measurement type.");
        inputType = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Ingredient amount");
        inputAmount = in.nextDouble();

        inputIngredient.setAmount(inputAmount); 
        inputIngredient.setName(inputName); 
        inputIngredient.setMeasurement(inputType);
        System.out.println(inputIngredient.getName() + "- " + inputIngredient.getAmount() + " " + inputIngredient.getMeasurement());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using:

```
double inputAmount = in.nextDouble();
```

which not only reads your first input amount but passes the carriage return to the next `readLine` statement.

The solution is to consume the carriage return first:

```
double inputAmount = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
```